# verificação de extenção de imagem para upload com php

Tags: php

Ola, criei uma pagina de cadastro onde o usuario pode inserir uma imagem de perfil, tudo funciona normal, exceto quando vou fazer a verificação da extensão do arquivo( sou novo em php) e utilizo esse algorítimo:

```
 if(!preg_match("/^image\/(pjpeg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)$/", $foto["type"])){ 
   $error[1] = "Certifique-se de o arquivo seja uma Imagem!"; 
}
```

quando retiro essa linha, funciona perfeitamente, qual o erro?
Obs: variavel que armazena a imagem $foto = $_FILES['pic'];

formCadastro.php

```
<form action="inserir.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="cadastro" >
   <fieldset >
   <label for="username"><span>Nome</span>
   <input type="text" name="nome" id="username" size="20" class="inputbox" title="Username" /></label>

   <label for="sobrenome"><span>Sobre Nome</span>
   <input type="text" name="sobrenome" id="user_sobrenome" size="20" class="inputbox" title="sobrenome" /></label>

   <label for="password"><span>Senha:</span>
   <input type="password" name="password" id="password" size="20" class="inputbox" title="Password" /></label>

   <label for="datanascimento"><span>Data Nascimento:</span>
   <input type="date" name="datanascimento" id="datanascimento" size="20" class="inputbox" title="datanascimento" /></label>

  <label for="email"><span>Email</span>
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" size="20" class="inputbox" title="email" /></label>

  <label for="pic"><span>Foto Perfil</span>
  <input type="file" name="pic" id="pic" size="20" class="inputbox" title="pic" /></label>

  <input name="enviar" type="submit" class="button2" value="Logar" />
</fieldset></form>
```

inserir.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_WARNING);//Odeio Warning X-X
$conn = @mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ("Conection Error!"); 
$database = @mysql_select_db("me", $conn) or die ("Conection Error!");

if($_POST['enviar']){
    $passwordUsuario = md5($_POST['password']);
    $emailUsuario = $_POST['email'];
    $nomeUsuario = $_POST['nome'];
    $sobreNome = $_POST['sobrenome'];
    $dataNascUsuario = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['datanascimento']));
    $foto = $_FILES['pic'];

    //verifica se a imagem foi selecionada e o tamanho do arquivo
        if(!empty($foto['name'])){
            $largura = 256;//Teste!
            $altura = 256;//Teste!
            $tamanho = 300000;//teste!

        //Verifica Tipo de arquivo enviado
        if(!preg_match('/^îmage\/(pjpeg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp|jpg)$/', $foto['type'])){
            $error[1] = " Verifique o tipo do Arquivo! ";
        }

        //Armazena dimenssões da Imagem
        $dimenssoes = getimagesize ($foto["tmp_name"]);

        //$largura maxima da Imagem
        if($dimenssoes[0] > $largura){
            $error[2] = "A largura não deve ultrapassar ".$largura."px!";
            }

        //$altura maxima da Imagem
        if($dimenssoes[1] > $altura){
            $error[3] =  "A altura não deve ultrapassar ".$altura."px!";
            }

        //$tamanho Maximo da Imagem
        if($foto["size"] > $tamanho){
            $error[4] = "A imagem deve ter no maximo ".$tamanho." bytes.";
            }

        //Sem  erros
        if(count($error) == 0){

            //Pega extensão da imagem
            preg_match("/\.(gif|bmp|png|jpg|jpeg){1}$/i", $foto['name'], $ext);

            //Gera id para Imagem
            $nome_imagem = md5(uniqid(time())) . "." . $ext[1];

            //diretório da foto
            $caminho_imagem = "fotos/" . $nome_imagem;

            //Envia a imagem para o diretorio fotos/
            move_uploaded_file($foto["tmp_name"], $caminho_imagem);

            //insere os dados no banco
            $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('', '".$passwordUsuario."' , '".$emailUsuario."' , '".$nomeUsuario."' , '".$sobreNome."' ,  '".$dataNascUsuario."' , '".$foto."')");  

            //Se não ouver erro GG!
            if($sql){
                    echo 'Bem vindo!';
                }
            }

            //se ouver erro ¬.¬)
            if(count($error) !=0){
                foreach ($error as $erro){
                        echo $erro . "<br />";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

?>

Comment: qual o erro que você está tendo?

Comment: a verificação está ok, você deve estar tendo problema em alguma outra parte do código, poderia postar o código completo pra darmos uma olhada?

Comment: Essa verificação parece correta. Está aparecendo algum erro?

Comment: sim! @Lucas "Verifique o tipo do Arquivo!", funciona perfeitamente quando retiro essa linha, cadastra normalmente, mais quando ponho pra verificar, ele da erro, tem outra forma de impedir o envio pelo extensão? não tenho muito conhecimento em php, estou estudando algumas funções basicas apenas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu não sei ao certo, mas parece que seu código está com o I invalido.

```
// errado
if (!preg_match('/^îmage\/(pjpeg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp|jpg)$/', $foto['type'])) {
    echo 'errado';
}

// certo
if (!preg_match('/^image\/(pjpeg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp|jpg)$/', $foto['type'])) {
    echo 'certo';
}
```

Outra observação.
Seu código é super inseguro. Pesquise sobre ***mysql injection***
E se está aprendendo, comece certo, usando alguma biblioteca PDO ou o próprio PDO.
http://br.phptherightway.com/ uma boa leitura para começar.

Comment: realmente! era isso mesmo esse carinha "|" mais essa tecla é o próximo ao shift esquerdo certo? será que é o teclado?muito obrigado! quando ao PDO não entendi muito, vou dar uma olhada..

Comment: é, escrever código as vezes faz esquentar a cabeça. 
um erro bobo faz agente perder horas tentando achar o que é.
Como esse carácter foi parar no i eu não sei, haha.

Sobre o PDO, ele ajuda a evitar sql injection.
Nesse seu atual código alguma pessoa mal intensioda pode usar o input nome para enviar comandos sql. O que pode resultar em você perder todo seu conteúdo, mostrar dados que o usuário n deveria ver, editar seu conteúdo sem sua permissão.